# Rails - Cannot seem to pass a parameter to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up a simple cart. I want to be able to click on 'add' on a record and then have that item added to the cart with the id of the record/line

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
  <td><%= link_to "add",  add_to_cart_path(8), :method => :post %></td>
<% end %>
```

I put the `add_to_cart_path(8)` as a troubleshooting. I really want that to be `add_to_cart(document.id)` however, either way, the current doc id parameter is not getting passed to the creation of the new item record.

My route is

```
post '/add_to_cart/:doc_id' => 'carts#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'
```

The carts controller has

```
def add_to_cart
  $current_doc_id = doc_id
  current_cart.add_item(:doc_id)
  redirect_to carts_path(current_cart.id)
end
```

my cart model has

```
def add_item(document_id)
  @line_item = Item.create(:document_id => document_id, :cart_id => $cart_number)
  if @line_item.save
    #  flash[:success] = "item added!"
  else
    #  flash[:fail] = "!"
  end
end
```

When I look at the items table, the record is being created and the cart id is properly populated. However, the document_id field is 'null'.

Comment: You're passing `:doc_id` symbol instead of actual document id. You should use your parameters via `params` method, for example `params[:doc_id]`.

Comment: That worked. The link is successfully passing the current document id.

Comment: You can use `better_errors` gem for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have the answer, but I wanted to clean up your code a bit...

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cart, only: [] do
   collection do
     post "add/:document_id", to: :create        #-> url.com/cart/add/:document_id
     delete "remove/:document_id", to: :destroy  #-> url.com/cart/remove/:document_id
   end
end

#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_document

   def create
     current_cart.line_items << @document
     redirect_to carts_path current_cart.id
   end

   def destroy
     current_cart.line_items.delete @document
     redirect_to carts_path current_cart.id
   end

   private

   def set_document
     @document = Document.find params[:document_id]
   end

end
```

This would allow you to use:

```
<%= link_to "Add to Cart", carts_add_path(@document), method: :post %>
<%= link_to "Remove from Cart", carts_remove_path(@document), method: :delete %>
```

You have a fundamental [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) in that you're using request-based logic in your `Cart` model. Models should only be for data-driven logic; request logic all needs to be kept within your controller:

```
if @line_item.save
    #  flash[:success] = "item added!"
  else
    #  flash[:fail] = "!"
end
```

... needs to be in your controller if you're relying on it to form a response.

---

We've set up a cart before (using a [`session model`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model)). You may benefit from the code we used. It's fundamentally different to yours in that it keeps the cart in a single session cookie, rather than saving the data in a model:

[image]

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cart do 
   collection do
       post   'cart/add/:id', to: 'cart#add', as: :cart_add
       delete 'cart/remove(/:id(/:all))', to: 'cart#delete', as: :cart_delete
   end
end

#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper

    #Index
    def index
        @items = cart_session.cart_contents
    end

    #Add
    def add
        session[:cart] ||={}
        products = session[:cart][:products]

        #If exists, add new, else create new variable
        if (products && products != {})
            session[:cart][:products] << params[:id]
        else
            session[:cart][:products] = Array(params[:id])
        end

        #Handle the request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
            format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
        end
    end

    #Delete
    def delete
        session[:cart] ||={}
        products = session[:cart][:products]
        id = params[:id]
        all = params[:all]

        #Is ID present?
        unless id.blank?
            unless all.blank?
                products.delete(params['id'])
            else
                products.delete_at(products.index(id) || products.length)
            end
        else
            products.delete
        end

        #Handle the request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
            format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
        end
    end

end
```

Then to show the cart:

```
#app/views/cart/index.html.erb
<% @items.each do |item| %>
   <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

I'll delete if inappropriate, I figured it would give you some perspective.